# Dynamic route called twice with different parameter value doesn't execute mounted method a 2nd time

Tags: vue-router

I finally thought I had found the solution for the horrible `NavigationDuplicated` error on $router.push.

For that, I have created a route: `/send/:id/pay/:payId` that executes `send.vue`.
If I call the route with `/send/xxx/pay/1111` and then with `/send/xxx/pay/2222` I expect send.vue to be loaded a 2nd time and the method `mounted` to be executed a 2nd time but it's not happening.
Only the 1st call executes `mounted`.

Shouldn't `send.vue` be loaded again?

Comment: You have to watch for route params change, because router doesn't reload component if it's the same route. See documentation [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

Comment: Thanks. I did that. It doesn't really work in every instance but now my app has improved.